# How to render one element of an array in mustache

Tags: javascript, mustache

If I have an object like

```
z = {"sname":"mike","lname":"michael","V":[1,2,3,4,5]};
```

Is there some way to specify that one element of `V` is to be rendered?  What goes in the template in place of `?????`?

```
T = <p>V={{#V}}{{.}} {{/V}} but V[3]={{?????}}</p>
```

If this is not possible, it would be useful to know that.

I can always construct separate V_0, V_1, V_2, V-3, V_4 entries but that seems VERY ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using lambdas to do the same. Although I am not very thorough about using partial I am guessing you could do this:

```
{
  "partial": function() {
    return function(array) {
      return  render(array[3]);
    }
  }
}

{{#partial}}
  {{.}}
{{/partial}}
```

Hope I got this right..

Comment: How does the partial know what array is being referenced?  Do I need a separate partial for every array/element combination?

Comment: {{.} is the array being passed into the function.. as you can see array is not pre declared anywhere..

Comment: so i end up defining a partial for every possible subscript & instead of writing {{V_3}} I write {{#V}}{{#partial3}}{{.}} {{/V}}{{/partial3}}{{/V}}?

Comment: I am nt sure.. I thought you wanted to make this a one of access.. else why would you structure your objects that way.. :/

Comment: seemed like a good idea until I found out I couldn't reference them. I have an array of about 50 such objects.  I ended up construction a different z from them with the name_0 business.